# How to distribute an app in beta in shopify ?(with App Bridge)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've got a stupid question. Could I distribute my app in beta if I want to use [App Bridge](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/app-bridge)?

From [what I see](https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/app-types), there is no solution expect to publish on the App Store or to be Shopify Plus service partners. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

1. you can make an App custom, and install on one store, and have no review by Shopify
2. you can make a public App, install on any test store, and test till you're happy, and have no review
3. you can have a review, and pass, but not go in app store.
4. you can have a review, and pass and go in app store.

You are your own Beta and you dog food your App using your own store till you're happy.